# Can I determine, using only a subset of polygon points, where the interior of the polygon lies?

Tags: algorithm, graphics, geometry

I'm attempting to render the subset of a polygon with a large amount of points (n > 100 000). I've decided to put the points of the polygons in a binary tree so that I can quickly find only the points situated in the view box and render them.

The problem that I'm trying to figure out here is: if I only get a subset of a polygon's points, how will I know where the interior of the polygon is? i.e, the area that I should fill? I've attached a picture below to further explain my question:

[image]

For the image above, given the subset of points of a complete polygon (returned after traversing the binary tree). Is it possible for me to determine which side (A or B) is the interior of the polygon, and fill accordingly?

If it isn't possible, is there a better way to store or retrieve the polygons to better find the interior of a polygon?

Comment: Better way than what ?

Comment: Thanks, edited the question to be clearer on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach would be to project a line horizontally left from your given point and find the nearest edge that that line intersects. The direction of that edge tells you whether the point is inside or outside the polygon (with a path direction imposed as per Paul's suggestion). If no edge is encountered, you are, of course, outside.

To achieve this, you need each cell of your binary tree to reference every edge that *passes through* the cell, *even if its vertices are outside the cell*. You may sometimes need to traverse through multiple cells to find the nearest intersecting edge.

To illustrate:

[image]

Within the cell that contains our point of interest (see the right-hand enlargement above), we project a line out from the point to the left. It meets no edges before it hits the cell boundary. So we must traverse into the next cell over, and continue our line. It hits an edge whose y-direction is positive; thus we conclude the point is *outside* the polygon.

Observe that a cell can hold information for vertices that fall outside the cell boundaries, so that every edge that passes across the cell is referenced.

This approach works for polygons of any complexity *as long as they do not self-intersect*, as well as shapes with multiple (unconnected) contours.

**Dealing with self-intersecting polygons:**

If you expect to encounter self-intersecting polygons, you can no longer tell if you are inside or outside by examining just the *nearest* edge. You must instead use the [non-zero winding rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) or the [even odd rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule), which require counting *all* edges to the left of your point.

In this case, you probably shouldn't bother making x-wise splits in your binary tree: instead let each cell cover the entire width of the polygon, and only split in the y-axis. There is little point creating multiple cells across the x-axis when on average you'll have to traverse through half of them anyway. This makes the algorithm simpler, as you only need to look at one cell to find all edges to the left of your point.

But you can go a step further. As you are only splitting in one axis, you can abandon your standard binary tree and instead use an [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) for best efficiency. The simplest variety is an *augmented* interval tree.

**An edge case (excuse the pun) to be careful of when coding this up:**

If your projected line passes directly through a vertex: this vertex is part of *two* edges, so which does the line hit first? It can make a big difference. To simplify this situation you should *only* consider an edge to be intersected if the y-position of the projected line is *strictly less than* the y position of the highest of the edge's two vertices.

Below are illustrated three points, whose projected lines pass through the lowest vertex, the mid-point and the highest vertex of an edge ('highest' meaning largest y-value; edge direction is unimportant here). The first two lines intersect the edge; the third doesn't.

[image]

As a result, perfectly horizontal edges are always ignored, and you can if you wish skip these when populating your binary tree (or interval tree).

If using an interval tree, you can deal with this edge case directly in the tree's search routine.

Comment: Thanks Ben. I really like this approach, its simple as well as easy to understand and implement. The only part I'm confused about is whether I should project left from my given point. It seems that it would add complexity as I wouldn't know if my given point is already inside a polygon or not (& therefore, whether a line intersect means I've entered or exited the polygon). Wouldn't it be better to start either from the left or right of the polygon's bounding box where I always know my starting point is outside the polygon?

Comment: @user1435899 If using the even-odd rule or the non-zero winding rule (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even%E2%80%93odd_rule), you will need to consider all edge intersections to the left of your point (and you might not bother with x-wise splits in your binary tree, making the algorithm simpler: there's little point splitting cells x-wise when you'll typically have to examine half those cells anyway).
But if you know the shape in question is not self-intersecting, you only need to consider the nearest edge to the left of your point. Its direction will tell you if you are inside or not.

Comment: I've updated the answer to better expand on how to deal with self-intersecting polygons.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and also usually taken approach) is to connect the vertices of the polygon in a linkedlist and arrange them such that the successors are arranged in counter-clockwise order around the area of the polygon. This way, the area of the polygon is always to the right of any edge.

[image]

Even if parts of the above square were covered up, you'd still be able to determine where the inside of the polygon lies. The sorting itself can be done in `O(n)`, if points aren't already in the appropriate order (quite likely).

Comment: this only works for convex polygon .... OP example image is clearly concave

Comment: @Spektre It also works for concave polygons. Just that they can't be arranged counter-clockwise anymore. But the basic idea of structuring the polygon such that the area is always to the right of the line works for any non-self-intersecting polygon.

Comment: See the last image in my answer ... It shows when your approach fails for concave polygons. If you have in mind different algorithm may be you should describe it in more detail.

Comment: @Spektre now I see. This was rather intended as a basis for a datastructure that can determine on which side of a polyline the interior of the polygon lies. It obviously can't solve the entire problem. Whether that's done with a linesweep or whatever is another story.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is dissect your polygons into sections like this:

[image: sections]

1. **chose some interior point `C` (Aqua center)**

   this point must be inside your polygon and its best if it is placed at the center of your polygon. You can obtain it as a center of BBOX, or center of a diagonal (line between any 2 points of polygon circumference far enough between each other like half of points) or intersection of 2 diagonals or as a average of all points or even randomly or however you want ...

   then just check if it lies inside polygon. This however must be done with slow approach (using all polygon points). Luckily this point is needed to compute just once (on creation/load/init of polygon).

   in case of wrong center just use different points to generate it or move it slightly until its inside.
2. **divide your polygon into sections**

   using diagonal lines (gray lines) between selected center and any polygon point. Select points so the sections have roughly the same number of points and the diagonal itself **must not intersect any polygon edge**. So if you got `m` points and want `n` sections use every `m-th` point as diagonal... and if it intersects use nearby point instead until it is correct.

   The section should be done also just once per polygon.
3. **faster inside**

   Now to detect if any point (Magenta) is inside first check which section it is by doing **CW/CCW** check between all diagonals or using `atan2` (in which case each diagonal angle can be precomputed once to speed up the process) finding two diagonals that envelope point in question:

   [image: section]

   so find diagonal which is CW to the point and has minimal angle ... and also another one that is CCW. If "center" point is `C` and tested point is `P` and diagonal points are `D(i)` then

   ```
   angle = acos(dot(P-C,D(i)-C)/(|P-C|*|D(i)-C|))
   ```

   and z coordinate of `cross(P-C,D(i)-C)` will tell you if the diagonal/angle is CW or CCW. I think you can ignore the `acos` as the nonlinear result without it should be still monotonic so `min,max` will be still correct.

   This will tell you in which section the point is so now do polygon inside check but use just the section points and used diagonals instead of whole polygon.

   Now when you have your 2 closest diagonals CW `D(i)` and CCW `D(j)` then just test polygon constructed from `C` and all points between `D(i)` and `D(j)`.

   [image: point inside section]

   As you can see the more sections you have the less points you need for checking (but more diagonals) ...

**PS** this note is for Paul

Algorithm using **CW/CCW**-ness works only for convex polygons on concave ones there are false negatives like in this image:

[image: error]

Comment: Thanks Spektre, a few questions, how is that interior point determined? And is it done at render time or during the building of the binary tree?

Comment: @user1435899 I added some more info you requested

Comment: The rules you give for finding a centre and dividing into sections will give very non-optimal results in some situations. If, for example, your polygon is the outline of a twisting snake, or the outline of a spiral, etc, you may be very limited in terms of what sections you can generate.

Comment: @BenWhitmore yep but there is no general approach for arbitrary concave polygons ...  this will work for most common shapes .... for specific polygon properties you need to tweak this ... like for paths you described you can use segments like thick polyline ... using BBOX of each segment instead of diagonals/angles ... but such subdivision would most likely need triangulation if topology is unknown...

Comment: @Spektre There is a straightforward general approach for arbitrary concave polygons; see my answer. It differs from the usual canonical solution only in that it uses a binary tree for faster edge search.